# passing argument 1 of 'better' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, arguments, function-call, variable-length-array, incompatibletypeerror

Here's a fairly simple program that finds the max element of an 2d array grades and prints it out to the screen

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int t = 5;
int num_of_students;
int better(int grades[num_of_students][t], int num_of_students)
{
    int i, k; 
    int max = grades[0][0];
    
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < t; k ++)
        {
            if (grades[i][k] > max)
            {
                max = grades[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int main(void)
{
    int i, k;
    printf("Give the number of students who took the test: ");
    scanf("%i", &num_of_students);
    int grades[num_of_students][t];

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %i\n", i+1);
        for (k = 0; k < t; k++)
       {
            printf("Give the score on test %i: ", k+1);
            scanf("%i", &grades[i][k]);
            while (grades[i][k] < 0 || grades[i][k] > 100)
            {
                printf("Not an acceptable score, try again %i: ", k+1);
                scanf("%i", &grades[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    int max = better(grades[num_of_students][t], num_of_students);
    printf("The best score is %i\n", max);
}
```

Yet when I'm trying to run the program the following errors pop up:
test.c:47:45: warning: passing argument 1 of 'better' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
test.c:6:16: note: expected 'int (*)[(sizetype)t]' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: `better(grades[num_of_students][t]` -> `better(grades`. Because you want to pass the entire array which is `grades`. `grades[num_of_students][t]` is a single element (and an out of bounds element at  that).

Comment: Don't read parameters from stdin, pass them as parameters: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int num_of_students = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1; ...`

Answer (score 1):

For starters change the function declaration from

```
int better(int grades[num_of_students][t], int num_of_students)
```

to

```
int better(int num_of_students, int grades[num_of_students][t] )
```

Otherwise it is unclear whether in the declaration of the first parameter  `int grades[num_of_students][t]` there is used the global variable `num_of_students` or the identifier of the second parameter. That is the function declaration as is will confuse readers of the code.

And call it like

```
int max = better( num_of_students, grades );
```

Otherwise you are trying to pass the non-existent element of the array `grades[num_of_students][t]` of the type `int` instead of the array itself.

Comment: in GCC or CLANG it is possible to make a forward declaration of a parameter. So one can use:
`int better(int num_students; int grades[num_of_students][t], int num_of_students)
` and later call `better(arr, num_of_students)`